# How to calculate an expression and group by 2 fields in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to write an expression in DAX that will group by 2 fields: AgentID and LoginDate. Here is the expression:

```
Average Availability % Per Day = (LoginTime + WorkTime) / (LoginTime + WorkTime + BreakTime)
```

What I have written in `DAX` so far is :

```
Average Availability % Per Day =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Logins[LoginDay] ),
    (
        DIVIDE (
            SUM ( Logins[LoginDuration] ) + SUM ( Logins[WorkDuration] ),
            SUM ( Logins[LoginDuration] ) + SUM ( Logins[WorkDuration] )
                + SUM ( Logins[BreakDuration] )
        )
    )
)
```

However, the problem is the expression is summing everything and then getting the average as opposed to evaluating the expression and grouping by each day and each AgentID before calculating the average.

EDIT: Adding sample data:

```
AgentID   |  LoginDay | LoginDuration | BreakDuration | WorkDuration
96385     | 7/5/2018  |    14472      |    803        |1447
96385     | 7/6/2018  |    14742      |    857        |1257
96385     | 7/12/2018 |    14404      |    583        |291
96385     | 7/13/2018 |    14276      |    636        |368
96385     | 7/19/2018 |    14456      |    788        |543
96385     | 7/20/2018 |    14550      |    390        |1727
96385     | 7/26/2018 |    66670      |    53224      |1076
96385     | 7/27/2018 |    14592      |    277        |1928
```

So for example, for this agent, I am getting an average availability % per day of .75 when it should really be .91

Comment: "VALUES function can only accept one argument" - can you explain why is that a problem for you?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your `Logins` data table looks like?

Comment: EDIT: New problem is that the expression is summing everything up and then getting the average as opposed to running the expression per each login day and getting an average of that number